# How to select the top row from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

```
 <?php

 //Step1
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','form')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

 //Step2
 $query = "SELECT * FROM info";
 mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $nam=$row['name'];
 $fnam=$row['father'];
 $date=$row['date'];
 $aadh=$row['aadhaar'];
 }
```

1.In this code it fetches all the values that are stored in the database . But I am in need of the code for fetching the top most row from the database.
2.The query with top attribute is also not working. It gives the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 * FROM info LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: why are you querying twice?

Comment: why are you looping twice?

Comment: *"It gives error."* - Being **what?**

Comment: btw... what is TOP for you? what is the criteria to order the records so that you will have a "first" one?

Comment: Show us sample data, table schema and which column to sort it.

Comment: Do you mean select the last data added?

Comment: this code doesn't hold much water, if you ask me. It's loaded with syntax errors.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 * FROM info LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: yes I need to fetch the last added data

Comment: Guess what that "1"` means......... right, just like I said in my first comment.

Comment: Seems like You've invisible symbol in Your code that makes it crash. Try to write that query (not copy-paste) in phpmyadmin or other MySQL GUI.

Answer (score -4):

This is not a PHP issue, it's rather a matter of your MySQL query.

This will return everything because of the * usage.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM info";
```

You can try this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM info
WHERE unique_id = (SELECT MAX(unique_id)  FROM info)";
```

Comment: The query shows "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&quot;SELECT * FROM info WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM info)&quot;' at line 1"

Comment: Max attribute is not working in my database which is working in w3 schools